# how to make sure all malloc'd memory has been freed?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I was wondering if there's a way to know the size of currently used malloc'd memory so I can compare before and after running tests to make sure all the memory has been freed.  Something like this:

```
size_t nmembytes_before = malloc_bytes_allocated();
... do your tests ...
size_t nmembytes_after = malloc_bytes_allocated();
if (nmembytes_before != nmembytes_after)
{
    ... error reporting ...
}
```

Does such a thing exist, or are we relegated to using valgrind for all our memory profiling?

Comment: You can easily write your own simple wrapper for `malloc` and `free` that will do the accounting.

Comment: That's a good idea.  It would be easy to add to the tally when calling my_malloc, but it would be hard to subtract from the tally when calling my_free (because the size of the object can't easily be determined from the pointer)

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html

Comment: You can also consider running your tests with `valgrind`

Answer (score 1):

Many heaps allow you to obtain statistics about allocations. Glibc offers: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html#Statistics-of-Malloc

This should allow you to test if all bytes allocated have been freed

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like none of the information in these statistics return the actual number of reserved bytes.  I did a test that was basically free(malloc(1024)) and the before and after were widely different.  However, there is some useful information in here.

Comment: Uordblks should be what you need.